# Assignment after not null check

Tags: kotlin, nullable

I expected that the type of a variable is promoted to a non-null type after a not-null check (like in the Dart language).

```
val someMap = mapOf("a" to 0L)
val a = someMap['a'] // a is of type Long?
if (a != null) {
    val b = a // b is of type Long? and not of type Long. Why? 
}
```

Can someone explain why this is not the case? Just a matter of taste of the language designers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is smart-casting, it doesn't matter. It will allow you to use members of `a` or `b` inside the if statement without null-safe calls (`?.`) or null assertions (`!!`). You can also safely declare `b` to be a Long without the compiler complaining:

```
if (a != null) {
    val b: Long = a
}
```

It is I think a design choice for how implicit types should be inferred that `b`'s type must be explicitly declared if you want it to be considered non-nullable. This is only relevant if passing it to a function with generics, since there is smart-casting.

Comment: That is indeed true. I just wonder why IntelliJ does not highlight `a` as being smart-casted without explicitly defining the type of `b` as `Long`.

Comment: I think the type of `b` is still considered `Long?` if you let it take the implicit value of `a`. This might be relevant if you passed it to a generic function. It's a behavior choice of the designers for it to only smart-cast if it explicitly needs to. Smart-cast highlighting in the IDE also seems buggy. Like if `a` is a `var` and I set it to null in the if-statement and then `println(a)`, it highlights `a` like it's being smart-cast even though it's null and the compiler complains if I try to use one of its members.

Comment: Good point, that might be the case indeed. I would upvote your answer but I've run out of votes for today.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do instead of explicit `null` check is using `let{}` as follows:

```kotlin
val someMap = mapOf('a' to 0L)
val a = someMap['a'] // a is of type Long?
a?.let {
    val b = it // b is of type Long
}
```

Comment: Mmm, this is a fairly common workaround. It also handles cases where the variable is a mutable field (and so could be modified by another thread in between the two uses), and/or where a more complex expression is being tested.

Answer (score 0):

It is called smart casting, basically Kotlin is smart enough to determine that variable can no longer be null after check. More detail and can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#smart-cast-types) if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

As to why, only the creators of kotlin can know. But what you can do is this if you want a `Long` instead of `Long?` there is this

```
val b = a!!
```